# Is pynfs stable to run on windows server 2008?

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-server-2008, ubuntu-12.04, nfs

I need to connect from a windows server 2008 in a secure network to an ubuntu box and write and read files easily from python code. I want to avoid samba or ftp, so I am considering NFS and my question is, if pynfs works stable on windows (if at all, or does it work on linux only?)

I found the source and some forks on github

I am also unsure about the state of the project, it is not in pypi, it cannot be installed over pip, so I wonder if this is a maintaned and updated project with a future. It would be great to hear from someone who has some production experience with it, I am using python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried it at all?

Comment: Hi Martin, I did not yet find out which of the versions or forks to use and I am hesitating to install on my produtcion machine before I have some further knoledge. Installing different versions one after another just to "try out" can have some disadvantages. If this were on linux I would just spin up a testing box, but I do not have access to so many windows servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer pynfs had some modern infrastructure around it.

I went with samba this time.

Answer (score 0):

pynfs  is a test suite and not ment to run as nfs server in production